# Multiple Insert in one query with MySqlParameters

Tags: c#, mysql, coding-style, mysql-connector

I am using `MySqlParameter` in my C# code.

With one record to insert, code looks like this:

```
        string query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO giveaways(giveaway_id, status) VALUES(@giveawayID, @status)";
        MySqlParameter[] parameters = {
            new MySqlParameter("@giveawayID", giveawayID),
            new MySqlParameter("@status", (byte) status)
        };

        await ExecuteNonQueryRetryAsync(query, parameters).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, I don't know how to achieve similar thing if I want to insert multiple records in one SQL query while still using `MySqlParameter`.

For now, I wrote something like this:

```
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("INSERT IGNORE INTO winners(giveaway_id, winner_id) VALUES");
        foreach (ulong winner in winners) {
            query.Append("('" + giveawayID + "'," + winner + "),");
        }

        query.Length -= 1; // Remove last char ',' from values
        await ExecuteNonQueryRetryAsync(query.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

It works, but it doesn't use `MySqlParameter` at all. Is there any better way to achieve that? I mean, I have to handle quoting literals and other stuff like that myself, when I don't need to worry about that at all when using `MySqlParameter`, which is also the better way IMHO.

So the actual question is... Is there any way to load MySQL parameter with an array or any other nice way to pass multiple values to insert?

Thank you in advance.

(Tagged coding-style because I'm in fact trying to write something better than what is written already)

Comment: for the quoted literals can you not use the string.Format function in your query.Append function..?

Comment: Yeah, that part probably can be written better, and I'll most likely rewrite it, but I wondered if there is a way to use MySqlParameter instead of doing all of that manually.

Comment: what do you mean instead of doing it manually..? also when I insert lots of data into Sql Server without using `Bulk Inserts` because our `DBA` turned off that feature in Sql Server, I create myself a temp table, then I pass in all my data one times from a datatable, converted into XML and do bulk inserts that way.. so much easier.. or you can create a user defined type on the db and do it that way as well..

Comment: I mean that when I use MySQL parameters I just load them, look at code sample #1, there's no quoting whatsoever. When I don't use them, I need to handle quoting myself. What you suggested above is better way to handle quoting - which I appreciate, but what I'm wondering is if there is a way to avoid quoting and load array into MySQL parameters instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with initial idea because of being unable to think of anything better, I just replaced `giveawayID` with MySQL parameter, because I could do that one thing.

```
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("INSERT IGNORE INTO winners(giveaway_id, winner_id) VALUES");
        foreach (ulong winnerID in winners) {
            query.Append("(@giveawayID, " + winnerID + "),");
        }

        query.Length -= 1; // Remove last char ',' from values

        MySqlParameter[] parameters = {
            new MySqlParameter("@giveawayID", giveawayID)
        };

        await ExecuteNonQueryRetryAsync(query.ToString(), parameters).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

If somebody ever finds out a better way, please don't hesitate to post it, I really hope there is a better approach.